# macOS - Background Image in NSView disappears on secondary monitor

Tags: swift, macos

I have following in my viewWillAppear of viewController

```
self.view.wantsLayer = true
let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "gradient_spot_bx"))
self.view.layer!.contents = image
```

Everything works fine when I am viewing my application on my MacBook screen. I have secondary monitor connected to my mac. When I drag my application from primary screen to the secondary, background image disappears. When I drag it back to the primary screen it reappears again. Any ideas why would this be happening? Im am on Xcode 9, Swift 4.

Comment: Your image resides in bundle, if not try to add it in your bundle or in Image Asset catalog and try.

Comment: My images are in asset catalog. I dragged them there so they are copied to the project. I have 3 image files gradient_spot_bx.png, gradient_spot_bx@2x.png, gradient_spot_bx@3x.png.  I do not know what is bundle and I do not understand from your message if images should or should not be in the bundle.

Comment: I found out am not using bundle. I read Apple documentation on bundle an it says: Some types of frequently used resources can be located and opened without a bundle. For example, when loading images, you store images in asset catalogs and load them using the init(named:) methods of UIImage or NSImage.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have found out that my secondary monitor color was set to: EPSON Standard RGB - Gamma 1.8. Once I switched to: sRGB IEC61966-2.1 which is what is on my primary screen they both look same now. I do not know if this is something I need to take care of in my programming, or users just have to have proper setting on their monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set the view's `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` to `.never`, then AppKit may discard the `contents` of the layer and recreate it with a call to `draw(_:)`. In your case, `draw(_:)` presumably won't restore the `contents` to be the same image you used in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I added self.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .never , still disappearing on secondary